# I want to randomly place an image in boundaries of parent div

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, position

I have some code that shows one or two random images form a list and places it in a random position in a div. Sometimes the images appear outside the div. How can I contain the images to only show in boundaries of parent div?

Current code :

```js
$('.draggable').each(function(i, el) {
  var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1 + '%',
    tTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1 + '%';
  $(el).css({
    'left': tLeft,
    'top': tTop
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-images {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-images img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-images">
  <img class="draggable" src="http://serwer1858479.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cincio/img/main/main_page(9).jpg">
  <img class="draggable" src="http://serwer1858479.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cincio/img/main/main_page(3).jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: please add generated html instead of php to give a better illustration of what's happening now

Answer (score 0):

in js get the width and height of each image...
      get the width and height of parent..
place the image randomly between 0,0 to (parent_width-img_width+1),(parent_height-img_height+1)

Note:new to js so the exact code might differ slightly but the general cocept is accurate

replace this in the math function

```
var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(el).parent().width()-$(el).clientwidth+1)) + 'px',
    tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(el).parent().height()-$(el).clientheight+1)) + 'px';
```

if the size is auto it might mess up the values

Edit 1: errors in the code

Comment: The images are different sizes and the height is set to auto. I can't seem to run this code. I think I get the idea but why are we adding the widths and heights? Shouldn't we substract them?

Answer (score 0):

Since 300px (width of images) is 43% of 700 (width of the div that images appear in)
you need to limit `tleft` to 57 (100-43). But `tTop` is a bit different since you used pixels for it. Try this :

```
var maxTop = $('.top-images').first().height() - $(this).height(),
tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 57) + 1 + '%',
tTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 'px';
```

Comment: I don't know why but tLeft works but tTop doesn't. Why are we adding the 0 before 'px'? You can see the page here http://serwer1858479.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/